# How to highlight custom bottomappbar icon and change appbar(top) title text flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello I am a complete noob but have been trying to work out a problem for a couple of days. I would like for these icons to be highlighted when they are clicked and for the AppBar title to change with the different page. The following code is just the skeleton I have, each button changes pages to other pages, but to keep this simple I used basic pages. In my actual code, each page returns a scaffold with a body and the content in the body. Should I just add an AppBar to each page and change the title there? Seems like a lot of work for the app. I truly appreciate any help you can offer.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DemoPage(),
    );
  }
}

class DemoPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DemoPageState createState() => _DemoPageState();
}

class _DemoPageState extends State<DemoPage> {
  PageController _myPage = PageController(initialPage: 0);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Title'
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        child: Container(
          height: 75,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Spacer(),
              IconButton(
                iconSize: 30.0,
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _myPage.jumpToPage(0);
                  });
                },
              ),
              Spacer(),
              IconButton(
                iconSize: 30.0,
                icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _myPage.jumpToPage(1);
                  });
                },
              ),
              Spacer(flex: 5,),
              IconButton(
                iconSize: 30.0,
                icon: Icon(Icons.notifications),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _myPage.jumpToPage(2);
                  });
                },
              ),
              Spacer(),
              IconButton(
                iconSize: 30.0,
                icon: Icon(Icons.list),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _myPage.jumpToPage(3);
                  });
                },
              ),
              Spacer(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: PageView(
        controller: _myPage,
        onPageChanged: (int) {
          print('Page Changes to index $int');
        },
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: Container(
              child: Text('Page 0'),
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: Container(
              child: Text('Page 1'),
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: Container(
              child: Text('Page 2'),
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: Container(
              child: Text('Page 3'),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Container(
        height: 65.0,
        width: 65.0,
        child: FittedBox(
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Icon(
              Icons.add,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            // elevation: 5.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a list _appbartitle with the list of title you need for each tab

Set a global integer to denote which page you are viewing

```
int page=0;
```

page==0 means Home, page==1 means Settings

```
_appbarTitle=['Home','Settings',];

AppBar(title:Text(_appbarTitle[page]))
```

Now rewrite each IconButton with this

```
 IconButton(
                iconSize: 30.0,
                icon: Icon(Icons.home,color:(page==0)?Colors.Blue:Colors.Black  ),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                     page=1;
                    _myPage.jumpToPage(0);
                  });
                },
              )
```

What happens here is when I click an IconButton in BottomAppBar, it sets the page variable accordingly and rebuilds the state, this leads to change in title of the Appbar according to the list _appbarTitle and I t sets the color of the selected IconButton to Blue.

Comment: I truly appreciate your help. I do apologize though, I am quite new to all of this, and I am quite lost. I spent the last couple of hours trying to learn lists and trying to make it work but I feel like I am getting nowhere. Could you please maybe show me an example of how I would make this list? Also, where do I put the global integer? Thank you for all your help!